# Installation of TYPO3 v9.5 fails in last step because of missing PHP library "argon2i"

Tags: typo3, mamp, typo3-9.x, argon2-ffi

I am trying to install TYPO3 v9.5.3 for the first time and fail in the last step of the installation routine (after submitting the form with the login details for the admin user).

As far as I could track this issue down, I think the problem is that I don't have the required library for argon2i compiled into PHP.

Now I found a very similar problem description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52799069), but I am not able to change the algorithm in the process of the installation.

Is there a way to use "bcrypt" or "phpass" right from the beginning (during installation)?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/PasswordHashing/Index.html, PHP 7.2 brings Argon2i support out of the box.

Also, this documentation page also says it falls back to other hashing algorithms if argon2i is not available.

---

So I guess that your guess about the missing lib is not the real reason.

Your question also does not explain what your actual error/problem is, so there is nothing more we can do here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The apache error log states: `[notice] child pid 9614 exit signal Illegal instruction (4)` which is not much of help for me.
I installed TYPO3 on a different maschine (with Argon2i support) and moved it to the server without Argon2i support. When I now try to login, I get the same error message in the apache error log.

Comment: That looks like a crash in PHP. "Illegal instruction (4)" means that it tries to  execute a CPU command that is invalid, which can happen if you use i386  code on an amd64 machine or vice versa.

Comment: Hm, the maschine where the installation fails is my local Mac with [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/) v5.2 running. The point why I am assuming that Argon2i is messing it up is, that I tried just calling the PHP function `password_hash('something', PASSWORD_ARGON2I);` which fails with the same error message in the apache arror log.

Comment: Yes, the command `php -r "echo password_hash('something', PASSWORD_ARGON2I) . PHP_EOL;"` crashes with the message `Illegal instruction: 4`, but `php -r "echo password_hash('something', PASSWORD_BCRYPT) . PHP_EOL;"` returns `$2y$10$ehuL./h5hoVlJHDKZiN0aOYfa6q6BHkzRKGOC.7TiezcinTzv7oWW`.

Comment: I think you should open a bug in MAMP.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but you can try to create `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php` before starting the installation process and put this into the file:

`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['passwordHashing']['className'] = 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Crypto\\PasswordHashing\\BcryptPasswordHash';`

Comment: Thanks Peter, I have tried `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['passwordHashing']['className'] = 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Crypto\\PasswordHashing\\BcryptPasswordHash';` (just one `['BE']`), but no luck.