# TYPO3 installation issue on Mamp

Tags: composer-php, typo3, installation, mamp-pro

trying to install the latest version of TYPO3 vers. 10.4 on my local machine. I am on a Mac and the local server is set up with Mamp Pro. Database is MySQL.

I am following this tutorial: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/QuickInstall/Composer/Index.html

I am getting to step 4 out 5. Manage to connect to the database, but it seems like it's freezing up at step 4. After a long while waiting, I then tried to refresh the browser. That's a success - getting to the final step. But I can't login with the username and password, that was just created. Then I tried to look in the Database, and there are no BE users. So it would seem like the installation is not complete.

Can you guys tell me, what I am missing here or doing wrong? Or perhaps others with a similar issue, that managed to solve this.

[image: Your login attempt did not succeed]

Comment: How is this related to Mac OS or Composer?

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54081267/installation-of-typo3-v9-5-fails-in-last-step-because-of-missing-php-library-ar) might be related.

Comment: Hi Chris, 
Thanks. I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54081267/installation-of-typo3-v9-5-fails-in-last-step-because-of-missing-php-library-ar), I had the same problem last year. I have just tested a fresh setup of TYPO3 10.4.1 without problems on my Mac with MAMP 5.5.

Since last year I have updated my MAMP. So I guess, that MAMP 5.5 is fixing this issue.

Comment: Thanks Chris,
I had some help with a fresh install. He did not succeed either. But he mentioned that the memory om my Macbook was used up. So that could be the reason, why nothing is inserted into the DB tables. So I will try to upgrade one of my machines and try again.